# Raven error logging on heroku. super: no superclass method `assert_required_properties_set!'

Tags: ruby, heroku, sentry, raven

I just pushed my ruby app to Heroku, and the Raven gem for sentry error logging is not working. It says this.

> super: no superclass method `assert_required_properties_set!'

What is going on and how do I fix this?